# trying to setup a vpn in kali linux but internet icon not working

Tags: kali-linux, vpn, vmware

I have recently installed kali linux 2.0 in VMware and been trying to setup a vpn. The tutorials available all point to the icon

[image]

being clickable, hence opening the option of adding a vpn. Is my linux broken if not then where can I find a tutorial where there is an alternative way of setting up the vpn.

Comment: I'd recommend learning to configure `openvpn` through [config files](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) and completely avoid gui administration for anything *nix

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. `apt-get install network-manager-openvpn`
2. `service networking restart && service network-manager restart`
3. Select "**Edit Connections**" from the network-manager icon and add `vpn`